# Regulating a 12V battery

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator

I have browsed the stack exchange for similar questions and while I found a couple of posts, I'm afraid they do not solve my problem.

I have a 12V battery, I understand it can go above 12V and naturally as it discharges - it will go under. I wish to have a regulator circuit which guarantees me 12V.

I have looked at a number of LDO converters such as MCP1804-COO2 (12V fixed output), but from the datasheet it seems this requires:

```
Vin >= Vout + 2V
```

Am I missing something? How do circuits with sensitive components guarantee the battery plays nicely? Any guidance would be really appreciated!

Comment: You don't use a linear regulator. You use a buck-boost converter.

Comment: isenwald (is that low-german for iron forest??): Sparkfun has [this product](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/18376) for doing something akin to what you need. @Hearth already told you to use *buck-boost* and that's what's needed for your case. You can either buy one (per the link) or else design and build one. But it must be buck boost and if this is for an automotive situation it may need other protections; against 'load dumps'. You do ***not want*** an LDO-only approach. Scratch that off your list.

Comment: A SEPIC converter can also provide this.

Comment: For what do you need 12.0 V exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your help all! @periblepsis indeed it is and thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

Get interested in a SEPIC type converter.

https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt309/slyt309.pdf?ts=1687512235025